# Is extracting method parameters as an object a good idea?

Tags: coding-style, refactoring

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/extract-parameter-object.html

I have always found extracting method parameters as an object a good idea, for methods which have a large number of parameters.

```
public void Method(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e);
```

becomes

```
public class Wrapper {A; B; C; D}

public void Method(Wrapper wrapper);
```

This allows me to:

- Have better readability in my code
- Perform validation of these parameters in the Wrapper class and reuse it across layers/components if need be.
- Provide less brittle method signatures.

Are there any other advantages/disadvantages you see to this that would help convince someone who's is writing methods with lot of parameters?. I am coding C# 4 if that makes a difference.

Comment: This might be OK for a set of parameters that are related.  If you have a large number of parameters, it is probably the case that there are independent subsets.  You don't want to couple the independent subsets together.

Answer (score 0):

The only disadvantage I can think of is having an additional abstraction in your system, requiring you to extract (although trivially) the actual data before access. I'm even not sure whether it can be called a disadvantage.

Most important advantage of parameters encapulation is having a robust well-defined interface which can accommodate future changes.

Answer (score 0):

A deeper advantage is that as you wrap the parameters in a new class, you realize that some behavior can be moved to the new class. This is because the bodies of the methods that modify the parameters are likely to manipulate the parameters similarly. Moving this common behavior into the new class allows you to remove much code duplication. Parameter validation is just one example of a behavior that can be moved into the new class.